# Thread safety in Services set to ConcurrencyMode.Multiple

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I am in the middle of developing a WCF application which is hosting a custom object for many clients to access. It's basically working but because I need to deal with thousands of simultaneous clients I need the service to be able to handle concurrent read calls (updates will be infrequent). I have added some thread-safety by locking private field while updating the object.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public sealed class TestServerConfig : ConfigBase, ITestInterface
{
    private object updateLock = new object();

    private SortedList<string, DateTime> dates = new SortedList<string, DateTime>();

    public DateTime GetDate(string key)
    {
        if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return this.dates[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    public void SetDate(string key, DateTime expirationDate)
    {
        lock (this.updateLock)
        {
            if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                this.dates[key] = expirationDate;
            }
            else
            {
                this.dates.Add(key, expirationDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to make GetDate thread safe without locking so that concurrent calls to GetDate can execute but so that an exception wont happen randomly when the value from the collection is removed after the check but before the value is read.

Catching the exception and dealing with it is possible but I would prefer to pevent it still.

Any ideas?

Comment: define "locking"?  Do you simply mean without using `lock(object)`? (or `Monitor.Enter/Exit`)

Comment: Basically I want to avoid any process/code/lock/whatever which limits GetDate to executing on a single thread at any one time.

Comment: Short answer is, you can't.  The act of testing for the existence of a value and getting the value is not atomic--you have to make that process appear atomic in relation to updates to it.

Comment: This sounds like a classic use-case for `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim`.

Comment: Do you have to use a `SortedList`, would a `Dictionary` work instead? If so there may be a [2nd solution that needs no locks at all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx).

Comment: You know, that should do the job! Although wouldn't you think it would do a similar thing under the hood?

Comment: Yes, but the locks are for smaller windows and they could potentially use unsafe internal methods to make it even faster. To get full potential you will need to rewrite your code so instead of checking for the key existing then updating you need to use functions like [AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378665.aspx) in your setter and [TryGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267270.aspx) in your reader.

Comment: OK well, I'll definitely go with this option, thread safe dictionary for free is a no-brainer. Maybe even post a new answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lock specifically designed for this, [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) ([ReadWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) if you are using less than .NET 4.0)

This lock allows concurrent reads, but locks out the reads (and other writes) when a write is happening.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public sealed class TestServerConfig : ConfigBase, ITestInterface
{
    private ReaderWriterLockSlim updateLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    private SortedList<string, DateTime> dates = new SortedList<string, DateTime>();


    public DateTime GetDate(string key)
    {
        try
        {   
            this.updateLock.EnterReadLock();
            if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return this.dates[key];
            }
            else
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            this.updateLock.ExitReadLock();
        }
    }
    public void SetDate(string key, DateTime expirationDate)
    {
        try
        {
            this.updateLock.EnterWriteLock();

            if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                this.dates[key] = expirationDate;
            }
            else
            {
                this.dates.Add(key, expirationDate);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
             this.updateLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }
}
```

There is also "Try" versions of the locks that support timeouts, you just check the returned bool to see if you took the lock.

---

**UPDATE:** Another solution is use a [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx), this does not require any locks at all. ConcurrentDictionary uses locks internally but they are shorter lived than the ones you could use, also there is potential that Microsoft could use some form of unsafe methods to optimize it even more, I don't know exactly what kind of locks they are taking internally.

You will need to do some re-writing to make your operations atomic though

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public sealed class TestServerConfig : ConfigBase, ITestInterface
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime> dates = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DateTime>();

    public DateTime GetDate(string key)
    {
        DateTime result;

        if (this.dates.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    public void SetDate(string key, DateTime expirationDate)
    {
        this.dates.AddOrUpdate(key, expirationDate, (usedKey, oldValue) => expirationDate);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2:** Out of curiosity I looked under the hood to see what `ConcurrentDictionary` does, What it does is only lock on a set of the buckets of the element, so you only get lock contention if two object also share the same hash bucket lock.

There is normally `Environment.ProcessorCount * 4` lock buckets, but you can set it by hand using the constructor that sets the [concurrencyLevel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287151.aspx).

Here is how it decides which lock to use

```
private void GetBucketAndLockNo(int hashcode, out int bucketNo, out int lockNo, int bucketCount, int lockCount)
{
    bucketNo = (hashcode & 2147483647) % bucketCount;
    lockNo = bucketNo % lockCount;
}
```

`lockCount` is equal to the `concurrencyLevel` set in the constructor.

Comment: Brilliant, I should have thought of this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a `ReaderWriterLockSlim` the documentation for which provides an example that is almost exactly what you want. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx )

But, something like this:

```
public DateTime GetDate(string key)
{
    cacheLock.EnterReadLock();
    try
    {
        if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return this.dates[key];
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cacheLock.ExitReadLock();
    }
}
public void SetDate(string key, DateTime expirationDate)
{
    cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        if (this.dates.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            this.dates[key] = expirationDate;
        }
        else
        {
            this.dates.Add(key, expirationDate);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

`ReaderWriterLockSlim` is much more performant than using a `lock` and differentiates between reads and writes, so if no writes are occurring the read becomes non-blocking.

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't afford locking for reads, you could (inside the lock), make a copy of the list, update it accordingly, and then replace the old list. The worst thing that could happend now would be that some of the reads would be a bit out of date, but they should never throw.

```
lock (this.updateLock)
{
    var temp = <copy list here>
    if (temp.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        temp[key] = expirationDate;
    }
    else
    {
        temp.Add(key, expirationDate);
    }

    this.dates = temp;
}
```

Not very efficient, but if you're not doing it too often it might not matter.

Comment: ReaderWriterLock was designed for Exactly this situation, and it performs a lot better.

Comment: That would be a great way of taxing the GC, not to mention making the WCF interface increase in response time over time...  Neither of which are very good, especially if the use of `lock` is needed to be avoided for performance reasons.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah I agree, that's a neater solution. Although if read performance is the only thing that matters, I'd think my lock-less version would be faster. Probably not by any noticeable amount though, but still.

Comment: @PeterRitchie I'd say that depends on how frequent the updates are, and how many items are in that list.

Comment: I did consider this as a solution but it would be really quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation and used ReaderWriterLockSlim and works these kind of situations.